# linking a received email with a sent email

Tags: c#

I have just completed reading received and sent emails using c# console application well that was easy part now the problem is I wanted to know is there a way of linking a received email to its replied/sent email like lets say i create a streamwriter and I write the contents that I need from the received email and the contents from the replied/sent email. How would I then go about knowing the received email to its replied/sent email? How would I link them? Uniquely differentiate from the tons of email?

Comment: Your problem is not clear by your question. What code do you use? From what source do you read emails and what is the current problem?

Comment: It's not possible to get it to work 100%, as you need to rely on headers.  Take a look at the spec; http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5322#section-3.6.4 - you can look at `In-Reply-To` in the email header.

Comment: May be you can add a link as attachment to the mail?